# React Native - Firestore Get specific Data

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, native

this is my Firestore structure: [Firestore Structur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABFnv.jpg)

The following items are already displayed in my first flatlist:
-noodels
-sauce

Now when I click on sauce, a new flatlist will appear with the following items:
-tomatoes
-onions

And now we come to my problem :)

Now when I click on "tomatoes", I want to display another flatlist called "spaghetti with tomato sauce".

As you can see in the photo, the ingredients are in a map and within the map I have 2 arrays.

I would like to know how to get the name if I already give "sauce" and "tomatoes".

Kind regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share your code and what isn't working?